# How to call different functions with a variable?

Tags: javascript

So i have this snippet, which obviously doesn't work, but it demonstrates what I want:

```
function myFunction1 (){doStuff();}
var x = 1;
myFunctionx();
```

Is there a way to make this work? Of cause i could do something like this:

```
function myFunction1 (){doStuff();}
var x = 1;
function call (){
 if (x=1){myFunction1();}
 if (x=2){myFunction2();}
}
```

But this gets really nasty really fast. Any help?

Comment: Use an object with properties whose values refer to your functions, and then use `[ ]` to fetch a function by name.

Comment: @Pointy — Since they are numeric, an array might be better.

Comment: Sure, an array would work fine of course.

Comment: `=` !== `===` !!

Comment: && = !== == && == !== ===